# MVC Incorrect View being displayed after form submission

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

One of my MVC view is not returning correctly after the form submission. The view in which I have my form is at localhost/Home/About (Home is the controller). After the form submits, it loads the main view or localhost. The form in my "About" view looks like the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#invoiceform>input").addClass("importGroupInvoice");
        });


        function setupInvoiceFormsForSubmission() {
            $("#ddlform>input.importGroupInvoice").remove();
            var $inputs = $("#invoiceform>input").clone();
            $("#ddlform").append($inputs);
            $inputs.css('display', 'none');

            //submit
            document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();
        }
</script>
<div style="margin-top:-3em"> 
    @model BTSWeb.Models.DropDownModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "invoiceform" }))
{
    <label style="color:black">    Type the name of the server you want to use. (Example - test-babyadept):         
 </label>
        <span style="margin-left:80px"></span>  

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server1)

       <p style="margin-top: -82px; margin-left: 730px; color: black; font-size: 17px">From:
    <input type="text" id="from" style="height: 18px; width: 70px; font-size: 12px"  ></p>
 <script type="text/javascript">


  <span style="margin-top:-80px"></span>  

        <label style="color:black">    If you wish you compare the results from two    
    </label>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server2)


 <p style="margin-top: -83px; margin-left: 752px; color: black; font-size: 17px" >To:
    <input type="text" id="to" style="height: 18px; width: 70px; font-size: 12px"></p>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById('to').value = (new Date()).getMonth()+1 + "/" + (new Date()).getDate() + "/" + (new Date()).getFullYear();
</script>

   }

<br>



<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Find Invoices" onclick="setupInvoiceFormsForSubmission()" />
```

The "About" view in my controller looks like following:

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var model = new DropDownModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

//

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(DropDownModel model)
    {

        stateId = model.SelectedStateId;


        paramcheck = "true";

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stateId.ToString());
        choice = "2";




        BillingToolInterface_1.Program p = new BillingToolInterface_1.Program(state, billtype, recurring, budget, paytype, IA, spanish, veteran, status, LDC, rate, adjustments, billtemplate, readtype, server1, server2, choice, paramcheck);

        //Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(caller));


        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DataJoin.Connector.data);

        model.Message = DataJoin.Connector.data;

        //model.SelectedBudgetId = 2;

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(choice);

        return View(model);
    }
```

UPDATE:
On further debugging I found out that every time I submit the form, the function for Index view in my controller is called:

```
[HttpPost][STAThread]
    public ActionResult Index(DropDownModel model)
    {
                  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("check");

                    return View(model);
    }
```

HTML form generated:

[image: HTML]
PS: Sorry for incorrect formatting. Still working on my stackoverflow skills.

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Hey, I am using MVC 3.

Comment: Your code looks Ok, it should re-show the `About` view.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Just added the setupInvoiceFormsForSubmission() function. If that might cause some trouble. ddl form is in my _Layout.cshtml, it's jquery to submit both invoice form and ddl form together. My best guess is this problem has something to do with the function.

Comment: What is the form action being generated in your HTML output?

Comment: Is the page that you're calling your controller action from in the same controller? I would still explicitly specify which View to display in your return statement as cross-references can play havoc with these types of situations.

Comment: @DavidG I added the generated HTML snip.

Comment: @krillgar how do I explicitly specify the view in my controller?

Comment: There are many overloads to `View` where the first parameter is a `string`, which is the name of the view. That'd be my first place to look for this. (I'm assuming you're using a break point and confirming that this is the actual Action that is being hit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript function to submit the form says:

```
document.getElementById("ddlform").submit();
```

However your form is called `invoiceform`

Change the JavaScript to:

```
document.getElementById("invoiceform").submit();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing that out. But that's the Jquery I am using to combine invoice form with ddlform and then to submit the comibined form. After changing it to invoiceform, I am getting the correct view but now my initial purpose is lost. Is there any way I can still submit the "ddlform" which is in my _layout.cshtml but return "About" as my view?

Comment: That's a different form completely though, and it's action will be set to post somewhere else. Is `invoiceform` contained inside `ddlform`?

Comment: No, invoiceform is in about view and ddlform is in my _layout.cshtml view.

Comment: Well you now have a different question. My answer gives you a solution to your question, but you now have a different problem.